# dataframe column gets deleted in Python but still present in Excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few dataframes like the following

```
    Unnamed: 0   c1  c2  c3
0       0        0   0   1
1       1        1   0   0
2       2        0   1   0
3       3        1   0   0
4       4        0   1   0
…
```

I've been trying to delete Unnamed: 0 with no success. If I drop it

```
df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

and then save the dataframe

```
df.to_csv('filename')
```

and then open it with Excel the column is still present. If I remove the column from inside Excel and load the dataframe again in Python, Unnamed has, yes, disappeared but the data appears in the format

```
      c1;c2;c3
0        0;0;1
1        1;0;0                      
2        0;1;0
3        1;0;0
4        0;1;0
```

Anyone can tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Are you talking about the index column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the index column of the data frame, you can use the `index` argument for [`to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method, and send in `False` value so that its not written to csv. (You do not need to drop the index column beforehand)

Example -

```
df.to_csv('filename', index=False)
```

Comment: Thnx man, that's what I meant. Now I can proceed with the concatenation of the data frames.